# Serious problem in android

Tags: android

I am doing an app where i have to download some videos from my server and i have to store them in internal storage of android device, but the problem is when iam storing the video in internal storage then the android not allowing to play that video if i am saving the same video on SD card it's working fine why it is happening i want to play the video from local storage.

Thanks,
Balaram.

Comment: How are we supposed to know why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it is best to store large data files in the SD Card as most users have very limited space on internal storage.

Also, take a look at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

It says "By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user)."

So if you are trying to use an another application to play the video, it is probably failing to read the file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But the downloading and playing both actions i am doing through the same app.